# Interrupt a reactive chunk in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app in which I have to run some lengthy calculations. These calculations use inputs from the user. I'm avoiding having a run button and would instead like to re-evaluate this chunk after the user hasn't changed the inputs for a certain duration. I'm able to accomplish this behaviour with `invalidate`.

However, if the chunk's evaluation is already underway and the user changes inputs in the middle, then the evaluation still continues with the previous values. I'd like to interrupt and terminate the execution with old values. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I don't know if you can interrupt an R process from within R. A possible solution is to call your lengthy calculation as a external process using `System(...)` and then later using system calls to interrupt it. Challenge would be to exchange result with Shiny (using file etc) and then find the external process pid so that you can interrupt it.

Comment: Haha. Might work but far too many moving pieces to be comfortable about.